# Heroku Rails 4 could not connect to server: connection refused

Tags: ruby, postgresql, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

Using postgres.
Haven't been able to push.

Tried this without any luck:

```
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

> -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
>
> ```
>    Running: rake assets:precompile
>    rake aborted!
>    could not connect to server: Connection refused
>    Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
>    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
> ```

Comment: Can you add to the question the error message you're getting?

Comment: You're trying to connect to PostgreSQL on localhost and it isn't running.

Comment: @tobeannounced to which file did you added the line: `config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false`? was it to: `config/application.rb`  or `config/environments/*.rb` ? Additionally, did you made sure you actually committed those changes to the repo before trying to push?  You might want to double check with `git status`

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The accepted answer did not fully resolve this. I tried to find a solution for 2-3 hours without success, then this worked:

In your app directory.

```
heroku labs:enable user-env-compile
```

it is still failing?

```
heroku labs:disable user-env-compile
heroku labs:enable user-env-compile
```

Then it worked for me, just had to remove and do again.

**The following config is no longer needed in Rails 4. Compiling assets must work without it.**

```
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

Comment: I was getting the EXACT same error due to a method error in one of my models.  After fixing that error I was able to push successfully many times.  Then, for some reason I started to get the error again...so, I added labs and that fixed it the second time.  Be sure to read your logs...

Comment: Heroku has now deprecated user-env-complile.I have this issue, unsolved.

Comment: As a workaround, I was able to compile assets locally, commit them to Git and push to Heroku.

Answer (score 6):

`config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false`

Include that in application.rb, ABOVE module APPNAME

I had originally included it inside

> class Application < Rails::Application

Edit: actually, the above didn't fix it.

I had to do this

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/labs-user-env-compile

Answer (score 1):

Try executing locally

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```

It might be because of **devise** gem as in my case. You might be missing secret key in devise initializer. try adding

```
config.secret_key = "PROVIDE-KEY"
```

Answer (score 0):

The heroku dev center talks about troubleshooting this. Basically your rails4 app should not rely on having config vars present during runtime.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline#troubleshooting

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Rolify pre version 3.5 then it might be that:

https://github.com/EppO/rolify/issues/221