# How to use postgres with rails on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, configuration

I am having the following contents in a database.yml

```
production:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: dbname
  host: host.compute-1.amazonaws.com
  username: user
  password: pass_word
  DATABASE_URL: postgres://user:pass_word@host.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/dbname
```

However on a git push heroku master, I am getting the following error.

```
could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Do I need changes for other environments as well?

Comment: Please remove DATABASE_URL from the database.yml

Comment: I have added it only after getting the error earlier, but without any change in error

Comment: you got the error while git push so can you please paste the total errors which you got while git push heroku master

Comment: Please also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16124490/heroku-rails-4-could-not-connect-to-server-connection-refused and also check  `config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

heroku autogenerates `database.yml` on the deploy.

You need to .git ignore `database.yml`

You may choose another database by setting the `ENV['DATABASE_URL'] (use heroku config:add DATABASE_URL=....)`

For more information please check the [heroku documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#build-behavior)

Answer (score 0):

DATABASE_URL is not required. Or you can check this one http://railsapps.github.io/rails-heroku-tutorial.html

Comment: Please see our comments

Answer (score 0):

This error

```
could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

is emitted during push, because be default Rails will spin up to precompile assets, and part of that is Rails trying to connect to the database.  During build time, your application configuration is not present, hence why Rails tries to fall back to the default of using localhost (which doesn't exist).

There's a couple of ways to stop this happening.  One (the recommended way) is to set

```
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

in your `production.rb`.

A second way, is to enable the `user-env-compile` labs feature that will allow your PG config to exist at build time.

```
$ heroku labs:enable user-env-compile -a <YOUR_APP_NAME>
```