# Getting Error while pushing into Heroku (Precompiling assets failed.)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2, heroku-postgres

Note: I am using Rails 3.2.13 and Ruby "1.9.3", and postgres-0.15.1

I tried to push my Ruby on Rails app in to heroku by following the procedure this website 
http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book#sec-deploying
, but I got error while try to push into heroku

> ```
>    Connecting to database specified by DATABASE_URL
>    rake aborted!
>    could not connect to server: Connection refused
>    Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
>    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
> ```

```
 !     Precompiling assets failed.
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app

To git@heroku.com:pure-hamlet-9148.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
```

So, I Googled myself and run the below command

> ```
> heroku labs:disable user-env-compile
> heroku labs:enable user-env-compile
> ```

Still getting the same error, please some help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Heroku Rails 4 could not connect to server: connection refused](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16124490/heroku-rails-4-could-not-connect-to-server-connection-refused)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this article about [Heroku and Rails asset:precompile error](http://simonecarletti.com/blog/2012/02/heroku-and-rails-3-2-assetprecompile-error/). You should set

```
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

Answer (score 3):

Along with Simone's answer,

Follow this website to precompile your assets locally before deploying. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
git add public/assets -f
git commit -m "vendor compiled assets"
```

Answer (score 0):

A way to resolve this error: 
First of all set DATABASE_URL environment variable & then again tried to push code to Heroku again. And it worked as all rake compilation done at Heroku side so no more connection to local machine making rake compilation @ .../tmp/bin..... directory.